# Close Modal on clicking outside the modal only if there are no changes made in form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, jquery-dialog

I have a modal with a form on clicking outside the modal i need to close the modal only if there are no changes are there in the modal. I am somewhat able to achieve it. I have written code on both on clicking a modal and outside the modal. But i need to trigger the function only on clicking outside the modal.

```
$(".modal").on('click',function() { 
    if(changed_data!= original_data)
      {
         var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
         if(result == true){
             $('#dialog').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = true;
             $('#form').removeData('bs.modal');
         }else{
             $('#dialog').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
         }
      }else{
            $('#dialog').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = true;
            $('#form').removeData('bs.modal');
          }
 });
```

Now i need to call this function only on clicking outside the modal. I found a option hide.bs.modal, hidden.bs.modal but they don't fit my requirement. If i use them the changes applied to the modal are showing there effect when i open the modal again. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

adding a `click` event after showing the modal, lock your modal to prevent it from closing, use your function and if it's ok to close, then unlock it and close it

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('lock');
    $('#myModal').on('click', function(e) {
        //do nothing if you're clicking inside the actual modal      
        if((' ' + e.target.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'modal-dialog' + ' ') > -1 || $(e.target).closest('.modal-dialog').length)
            return;

        if(changed_data != original_data)
        {
            var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
            if(result == true){
                $('#myModal').modal('unlock').modal('hide').off("click");
            }
        }else{
            $('#myModal').modal('unlock').modal('hide').off("click");
        }
    });
});
```

**edit**

oh, just remembered that I use `lock` and `unlock` because I'm extending my base modals to have these. to allow lock and unlock to work with your modals use this code inside `$(document).ready`

```
// save the original function object
var _superModal = $.fn.modal;

// add locked as a new option
$.extend( _superModal.Constructor.DEFAULTS, {
    locked: false
});

// capture the original hide
var _hide = _superModal.Constructor.prototype.hide;

// add the lock, unlock and override the hide of modal
$.extend(_superModal.Constructor.prototype, {
    // locks the dialog so that it cannot be hidden
    lock: function() {
        this.options.locked = true;
    }
    // unlocks the dialog so that it can be hidden by 'esc' or clicking on the backdrop (if not static)
    ,unlock: function() {
        this.options.locked = false;
    }
    // override the original hide so that the original is only called if the modal is unlocked
    ,hide: function() {
        if (this.options.locked) return;
            _hide.apply(this, arguments);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hi FabioG what does modal-dialog in if statement specify

Comment: it's checking if your not clicking inside the actual modal as oposed to outside of it. `.modal` is the parent class it includes the backdrop and actual dialog of the modal, `.modal-dialog` is the class for the modal itself where your content goes

Comment: Hi FabioG, you suggested to write the code on showing a modal but i will get changed data after showing the modal before closing the modal. If i use your your code i will get original and changed data as same

Comment: how are you setting `changed_data`? and `original_data` too, by the way